# Parsing complex HTML tables

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to parse the class schedule provided by my university in order to import the information into some kind of calendar.
An example of the schedule can be seen here:
http://www.asw-berufsakademie.de/fileadmin/download/download/Sked%20Stundenplan/WIA13-7.%20Block.html

The auto-generated HTML-content is, in my opinion, a mess and very hard to grasp. E.g. the tables are mainly built with rowspans and colspans (the positions of cells in the code compared with their actual visual position in the browser seem partially arbitrary).

What I've already tried:

1. Asking the university's administration office to provide a simpler, easier to read file separately. Of course this wasn't possible, after all it would mean one minute of additional effort.
2. Researching the original tool used to generate the HTML. It is called "sked Stundenplan Software". I couldn't find any hints or tools to "reverse" the generation process.
3. Looking for an existing solution, at which point I found some tools (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/skd-schedule-parser/) that do not work for my schedule. After studying the codes of these tools I concluded that they must have been designed for an other/outdated version of sked.
4. Parsing the HTML with PHP (mostly using DOMDocument). That worked sometimes, but was way too unreliable...The exceptions to take into account seem indefinite.

Right now I don't think that conventional HTML parsing will get me far, at least not in an acceptable developing time.
What I am looking for are other methods to fetch information from complex HTML tables, something like YQL, or maybe utilities that can normalize such tables with col-/rowspans.
Because I don't have anything concrete in mind, I am mainly asking for some tips or hints for another approach.

Are there other, more suitable methods to parse such tables or am I stuck with conventional HTML parsing?

**Edit:**

On behalf of a request, I'll paste an example of raw code...

This week:
[image: Schedule week]

Results from this code:
http://pastebin.com/BJduUVtU

**Edit 2:**
Because of some parsing discussions I'll also add my PHP code. It's my first time with PHP so it's not very sophisticated. It should rather give an insight on how far I've come with parsing the tables in theory. The actual work happens in the function *parseSkedTable()*, please concentrate on this one. Also, I would like to point out the term "double courses" appearing in the comments, which describes two different courses happening at the same time (the class would be split in such moments). An example of these courses can be found here in week two:
http://www.asw-berufsakademie.de/fileadmin/download/download/Sked%20Stundenplan/WIB14-4.%20Block.html

It looks like this:
[image: Double courses]

The corresponding **HTML-code** of that week can also be accessed here:
http://pastebin.com/gLTWz5KU

And now the **PHP-code** (I had a hard time translating the comments since I already struggled expressing them in my first language...I hope they may still be helpful):
http://pastebin.com/Nzi8m2v8

**Update**

So far, there have been some solutions to my parsing problem, each of them using JavaScript. Since JavaScript (being especially powerful here because of the ability to use browser-rendered data) seems to be the only efficient way to retrieve reliable information from the HTML, I am now looking for a way to implement some kind of headless browser or rendering engine on my free server at x10hosting.com. Sadly, I am neither able to install software other than provided by [softaculous](http://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/apps) nor allowed to use PHP's *exec()* command.
Any idea would be appreciated!

For the sake of completeness, I'll post both solutions, existing until now:

1. [jQuery parser](http://jsfiddle.net/3t2A8/2/) *by Pierre Dubois*:

   (function ($) {
       $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
       var _pe = window.pe || {
           fn : {}
       };

       var tblNumber = 0; // Just a incremental number to identify the schedule item with the table

       // For each table
       $('table').each(function () {

           $('#output').append('Parsing the table number: ' + tblNumber + '<br>');
           // console.log('Parsing the table number: ' + tblNumber);
           tblNumber += 1;

           var currentTable = this;


           // Parser the complex table
           _pe.fn.parsertable.parse($(currentTable));

           // Retrieve the parsed data
           var parsedData = $(currentTable).data().tblparser;

           //
           // Information about the column structure, nice that is consistent
           //

           // Day: Cell index position (0 based)
           // Mo: 3
           // Di: 7
           // Mi: 11
           // Do: 15
           // Fr: 19
           // Sa: 23

           // Title Location at Row index position "0"

           // "i" represent the middle column position
           for (var i = 3; i < 24; i += 4) {

               var currentDay;

               // Get the day
               currentDay = $(parsedData.row[0].cell[i].elem).text();

               $('#output').append('  Day: ' + currentDay + '<br>');
               // console.log('Day: ' + currentDay);

               // Get all the events for that day, excluding the first row and the last row
               for (var j = 1; j < parsedData.col[i].cell.length - 2; j += 1) {

                   // First column 
                   if (parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].uid ) {

                       // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                       var event = $(parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                       if (event.length > 0) {
                           $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                           // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                       }
                   }

                   // Second Column
                   if (parsedData.col[i].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid &&
                       parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].uid !== parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid) {

                       // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                       var event = $(parsedData.col[i].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                       if (event.length > 0) {
                           $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                           // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                       }
                   }

                   // Third Column
                   if (parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].uid &&
                       parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid !== parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].uid) {

                       // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                       var event = $(parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                       if (event.length > 0) {
                           $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                           // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                       }
                   }
               } 

           }

       });


   });
   ```

   }(jQuery));
2. [JS parser using positional
       information](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Zhw/2/) *by me, realizing rambo
       coder's idea*

Comment: Oh brother. I'm not sure whether a tool exists to parse *that* kind of a mess. ("Mess" from a HTML point of view. Visually, it looks pretty neat!)

Comment: Side note: on Stack Overflow, we aim for self-contained questions that are valid even when external sites go down. Could you post an example of the kind of HTML code that you need to parse in here? Use the `{}` button to format it as code. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care about the rowspans when the time is in the cells?  Why don't you just create a hash/array of dates pulled from the header and then only worry about the columns and parse the text for the time?  Looks pretty simple using any of the standard XML parsing methods and basic regex.

Comment: @Matt look at the table. It's a total, utter catastrophe in terms of programmatically interpreting anything. I bet a 3-hour course would be marked by a cell that has an increased `rowspan`... good luck parsing that.

Comment: @Pekka It's very noisy but within that noise there's very little data and therefore very little context that would need to be tracked/associated.  If you only worry about text children within a sparse matrix it would slim way down.

Comment: @MCL I think your best guess is to contact the author of Sked. I did that with WebUntis (similar to Sked) and it turned out that they had a JSON API.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer - Thanks...you probably want that to go to the OP though (I honestly don't care that much) :)

Comment: @Matt ahh, I see what you mean - concentrate on the data cells only, fetch the time from there. That might work, if you can assign each cell to a day of the week.

Comment: @MattWhipple Sorry, confused you with OP. Edited.

Comment: It looks like the <td> elements that you're interested in all have "class='v'", so you could probably just parse those, and ignore everything else.

Comment: @Pekka I am trying to add a fairly large code snippet, the request doesn't seem to finish. Is there a character limit per post?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek this is correct. Unfortunately, these cells only have infos about the time of day, not the day itself. I'll have to assign a date to each of these cells. Therefore, their position (and some other stuff) becomes relevant again.

Comment: @MCL I think counting the `.r2` before a `.v` (until to the beginning of a row) gives you the horizontal position.

Comment: @MCL Can you post it on a reliable pastebin then?

Comment: Are there any limitations on what technologies you use to extract data (e.g. PHP only)?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer PHP would be preffered. I want to process the schedule with a server on a job basis and I depend on a free alternative which imo leaves only PHP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18341/discussion-between-markus-unterwaditzer-and-mcl)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a browsers rendering/layout engine here.

Use http://phantomjs.org/ to get access to a headless browser that lets you execute javascript on a webpage's dom.

A dash of jquery would make the remaining pseudocode easy to implement:

```
foreach (td.t as dateElement) {
    //parse date from element text
    //use pixel position + dimensions to calc pixel coord of center
    // save this center in a list along with the date
}

foreach (td.v as calendarEntryElement) {
    //parse time + other stuff from element text
    //use pixel position to find the closest date element in that list(it must be the closest one above)
}
```

I feel positional information would be very reliable here, because everything is a nested rectangle and its all done via tables.

You don't *need* to use phantomjs, you could just as easily execute a browser manually, and let it send a request to a local server to collect the results.

Some shell command roughly like

```
firefox file://foo123.html
```

Where you've appended some custom `<script>` to the end of one of their webpages and saved it.

Comment: I adopted that idea and wrote a quick Userscript, it seems to work very well in Chrome. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/d6QG7mv7 Is there an easy way to implement this in a PHP based script? My server is hosted at x10hosting.com (free), so I don't have many persmissions.

Comment: If you have shell access, and can use php's program execution functions like exec(), I think you'll be ok. But otherwise, I can't think of any straightforward way. If you don't need realtime data collection, you could have your home computer periodically(cron/scheduled task) download a list of pending jobs from the web server, complete them, and upload the results.

Comment: I've been looking for ways to render JavaScript combined with HTML and I feel like I'm running out of options. Apparently, I am only allowed to install software provided by [softaculous](http://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/apps). There doesn't seem to be any kind of JavaScript engine or headless browser available. Is there a simple includable library that I just can't find, to get the job done?

Answer (score 1):

I study at the same university and a few weeks ago I faced the same problem to parse this time table and convert it to an ICS file. Finally I found my own solution and generalized the code, so that students from other universities, using the Sked software and have a much more complex time table, can import their time table too.
I also created a website, where students can sign up and configure the urls to the time tables which they want to subscribe. In the background runs a cronjob which ensures, that the subscribed calendars are always up to date.
You can find the result of the project on my website:
 http://calendar.pineappledeveloper.com/ 
(it is only in German available).

Comment: you are not really answering the question, just showing a result of a similar project, but not the information to resolve the issue, also, being in german doesn't guarantee that everyone in SO can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Many developers use HTML Agility Pack to parse HTML:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have some hope for your problem since the html is well formed and is x-html compliant.

The following Java program parse it successfully but without extracting information.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public final class AgendaParser {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Throwable {
      long atStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse( "WIA13-7. Block.html" );
      System.err.println( "Elapsed time: " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - atStart ) / 1000L + " seconds" );
      System.err.println( doc.getElementsByTagName( "table" ));
   }
}
```

it outputs:

```
Elapsed time: 118 seconds (very long, no?)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@7faea002
```

I thing a couple of hours of work gives you 80% of the extraction.

Answer (score 0):

Interresting complex table. A mix between a layout table and a data table.

This may help you, that solution is in jQuery and use the same complex table parser available in the [Web Experience Toolkit Project](https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew). With that table parser, you will be able to retreive your schedule data. The only thing that need to be done would be to parse the schedule item content for the importation to your calendar apps.

This solution **use the column** instead of the row to retrieve the schedule items

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/3t2A8/2/

Here the javascript code that is used to extract and show the schedule items

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var _pe = window.pe || {
            fn : {}
        };

        var tblNumber = 0; // Just a incremental number to identify the schedule item with the table

        // For each table
        $('table').each(function () {

            $('#output').append('Parsing the table number: ' + tblNumber + '<br>');
            // console.log('Parsing the table number: ' + tblNumber);
            tblNumber += 1;

            var currentTable = this;


            // Parser the complex table
            _pe.fn.parsertable.parse($(currentTable));

            // Retrieve the parsed data
            var parsedData = $(currentTable).data().tblparser;

            //
            // Information about the column structure, nice that is consistent
            //

            // Day: Cell index position (0 based)
            // Mo: 3
            // Di: 7
            // Mi: 11
            // Do: 15
            // Fr: 19
            // Sa: 23

            // Title Location at Row index position "0"

            // "i" represent the middle column position
            for (var i = 3; i < 24; i += 4) {

                var currentDay;

                // Get the day
                currentDay = $(parsedData.row[0].cell[i].elem).text();

                $('#output').append('  Day: ' + currentDay + '<br>');
                // console.log('Day: ' + currentDay);

                // Get all the events for that day, excluding the first row and the last row
                for (var j = 1; j < parsedData.col[i].cell.length - 2; j += 1) {

                    // First column 
                    if (parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].uid ) {

                        // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                        var event = $(parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                        if (event.length > 0) {
                            $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                            // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                        }
                    }

                    // Second Column
                    if (parsedData.col[i].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid &&
                        parsedData.col[i - 1].cell[j].uid !== parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid) {

                        // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                        var event = $(parsedData.col[i].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                        if (event.length > 0) {
                            $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                            // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                        }
                    }

                    // Third Column
                    if (parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j - 1].uid !== parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].uid &&
                        parsedData.col[i].cell[j].uid !== parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].uid) {

                        // Get the content of that cell and remove ending space
                        var event = $(parsedData.col[i + 1].cell[j].elem).text().trim();

                        if (event.length > 0) {
                            $('#output').append('  + Event: ' + event + '<br>');
                            // console.log('Event: ' + event);
                        }
                    }
                } 

            }

        });


    });

}(jQuery));
```

it would output for the "double courses" table

```
Parsing the table number: 0
  Day: Mo, 22.10.2012
  + Event: 12:45 - 14:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 1
      HG: 13
  + Event: 12:45 - 14:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  + Event: 14:30 - 16:00 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 1
      HG: 13
  + Event: 14:30 - 16:00 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  + Event: 16:15 - 17:45 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 2
      HG: 13
  + Event: 16:15 - 17:45 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 1
      HG: 15
  + Event: 18:00 - 19:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 2
      HG: 13
  + Event: 18:00 - 19:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 1
      HG: 15
  Day: Di, 23.10.2012
  + Event: 9:00 - 10:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 2
      HG: 13
  + Event: 10:45 - 12:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 2
      HG: 13
  + Event: 12:45 - 14:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 1
      HG: 13
  + Event: 14:30 - 16:00 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD Gr. 1
      HG: 13
  + Event: 16:15 - 17:45 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 1
      HG: 15
  + Event: 18:00 - 19:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 1
      HG: 15
  Day: Mi, 24.10.2012
  + Event: 9:00 - 10:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD
      HG: 09
  + Event: 10:45 - 12:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      DATMOD
      HG: 09
  + Event: 12:45 - 14:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      IuF
      HG: 09
  + Event: 14:30 - 16:00 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      IuF
      HG: 09
  Day: Do, 25.10.2012
  + Event: 12:45 - 14:15 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  + Event: 14:30 - 16:00 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      PROG III Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  + Event: 16:15 - 17:45 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      Linux Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  + Event: 18:00 - 19:30 Uhr
      Vorlesung
      Linux Gr. 2
      HG: 15
  Day: Fr, 26.10.2012
  Day: Sa, 27.10.2012
  + Event: 9:00 - 11:15 Uhr
      Klausur
      MP INT RW
      HG: 14
```

:-)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. A method based on JavaScript (using positional information) has been discussed before (s. rambo coder's answer and the respective comments). My current problem is implementing this on a server using only PHP without being able to install additional software. My server is hosted at x10hosting.com; I am willing to use another alternative, as long, of course, it is for free ;)

Comment: However my trick is on generating a new table where each cell is split in his smaller size, where the rowspan and colspan have no effect. After you have just to navigate on the cells by using the appropriate column. You can use the DOM php class or/and SimpleXML php class to help you to navigation on the table node structure. With that it's possible to migrate the [Line 1025 to Line 1292](https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/blob/master/src/js/dependencies/parserTable.js#L1025) from the table parser where for each row it create the cell in his smaller size. :-)

Answer (score 0):

pseudoPHP

```
class ScheduleTableParser {
  buildTimetableFromTable() {
    //Trivial
    Parse Day Rowspans, Day Names, Dates into $this->days;
    e.g. $days[0]['rowspan'] = 4 for Monday 22/10/2012

    //Extract Lessons      
    $tr = 0;
    foreach tr {
      $td = 0;
      foreach td{
        if(td.class = 'v') {
          parseClass($td,$tr,$tdDOMObject);
        }
        $td++;
      }
    }
 }
 parseClass($td,$tr,$tdDOMObject) {
   //Trivial
   Get the Class Name Etc   

   //Calculate Time
   $time = 9:00 + 5mins*tr;
   $tr = $tr - 2;
   $i = 0;
   while($tr > 0) {
     $tr - $this->days[$i]['rowspan'];
     $day = $this->days[$i]['name'];
     $date = $this->days[$i]['date'];
     $i++;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't enough. The td.v elements do not contain information on the date they refer to, which naturally is an essential part. Please q.v. the comments of my question.