# How to get sorted Values from HTML Table in C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, html-agility-pack

Hello fellow Programmers.
I now spend a whole Day reading Threads to solve this Problem. 
I am Parsing HTML from an automatic generated schedule, the same schedule programm was discussed 6 years ago on this thread: [Parsing complex HTML tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988863/parsing-complex-html-tables)

But this java / javascript solutions wont work for me. Also the mentioned Programs arent working anymore, I think they released a new Version of the Software. This is the Example I am trying to Parse: https://www.ostfalia.de/cms/de/b/studium/stundenplaene/download/ss19_b_stdgrp_ai_6.html

I need the Parsed Data in the right sequence because I want to generate an iCalendar file with it, or pass/send the data into an self written schedule App

I am using the HTML Agility Pack and Im already sucessful with parsing what I need but I cant get it in the right order its complete split because the HAP displays by row like any other parser. Im so desperate I was close to just count the emtpy trs to estimate when a new row begins but this doesnt work because the program has sometimes more sometimes less empty lines. Does somebody of you has an idea?

This is my Code to get the infos I need:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string html = client.DownloadString("https://www.ostfalia.de/cms/de/b/studium/stundenplaene/download/ss19_b_stdgrp_ai_6.html");

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var erg = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='v']");

        for (int i = 0; i < erg.Count; i++)
        {
            txt_check.Text = (erg[i].InnerText);
            list_check.Items.Add(erg[i].InnerText);
        }
```

"class v" is the event and "class t" is the time in this example its just class v

I get:

The output of class='v' looks like:

10:30 - 12:00 UhrAI 6.1 Komponentenbasierte SoftwareentwicklungB. RogallaB 109

13:00 - 14:30 UhrAI WPF-12 CCNA 2 Cisco Routing & SwitchingChr. HollmannA 201

13:00 - 14:30 UhrAI WPF Inst. u. Betrieb einer Datenb. a. B. OracleD. HeringA

14:45 - 16:15 UhrAI WPF Mathematik III für InformatikerT. WaldeerB 27 114

14:45 - 16:15 UhrAI WPF-18 AutomatisierungstechnikF. DziembowskiA 107

The output of class='t' looks like:

"Di, 05.03.2019"

"Mi, 06.03.2019"

"Do, 07.03.2019"

"Fr, 08.03.2019"

"Sa, 09.03.2019"

I hope someone has an idea how I can Sort and Match the informations in an Dictionary or List to get it in an ICS.

The Output should be like:

"MI, 06.03.2019 , 8:45 - 10:15 ,AI 6.1 Komponentenbasierte Softwareentwicklung B. Rogalla B109 , 10:30 - 12:00 AI 6.1 Komponentenbasierte Softwareentwicklung B. Rogalla B109"

...
So I can bring it in the ICS Format or DATE/TIME for an Calendar App or something.

Pastbin for the whole HTML:
https://pastebin.com/hHbJTujN

Some Pictures of the Output:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Y_hISdVEvzlrS6LCmBMcwAarGhz__t0

Comment: The first thing to try is to contact the website and ask if they have an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) you can use to get the data in a format which you can use more easily, for example XML or JSON. My German is too poor to be able to have a look for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hey, Thanks for your Comment. The Website is hosted by my University. I already asked them but they said to me that they just give in the Dates and Times an the Software creates the Pages they just add them on their ftp and link them via Hyperlinks. That was also the Problem in the old Thread that was the first Thing I asked them.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth asking them again in case they had improved the access to the data.